# Angular ngClass does not change the value of the class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<div class="search-input">
            <div class="selects">
              <div class="icon fluid select" ng-init="focused=false">
                <i  ng-class="{'large svg icon guests {{focused}} ':rooms==2, 'large svg icon guest {{focused}}':rooms==1}"></i>
                <label ng-click="closeCalendar();">
                  <select ng-model="rooms" ng-change="focused=true" name="rooms" class="fluid" name="rooms" focus-parent selecter required>
                      <option value="1">Einzelzimmer</option>
                      <option value="2">Doppelzimmer</option>
                  </select>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I want to change the class of the  when the user clicks on the select so I have the ng-change to turn the value into true, when the page loads, I have:

```
ng-class="{'large svg icon guests {{focused}} ':rooms==2, 'large svg icon guest {{focused}}':rooms==1}"
```

and

`class=large svg icon guests false`

which I supposed is correct, when the user clicks the select the first line becomes

```
ng-class="{'large svg icon guests true ':rooms==2, 'large svg icon guest true':rooms==1}"
```

but the class is still `large svg icon guests false`

Any idea why the class does not change?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<i  class="large svg icon {{focused}}" ng-class="{guests:(rooms==2), guest:(rooms==1)}"></i>
```

you are trying to interpolate inside a directive, i believe a better solution would be to separate the interpolation from the conditional as stated above.  you can have all your stateic classes and your interpolation inside the usuall class tag and then use ng-class only for the conditional ones

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Generic why  do you say it didn't provide an answer? was it too short? Help me understand so i don't make the same mistake again

Comment: Before you edited it, your answer was just a single line of code. It showed up in the low quality posts queue, and I reviewed it as not an answer because it had no explanation that addressed the question "why does the class not change?".

Comment: Thanks, ill avoid that kind of answers in the future